# How to interpretate following Spring EL

Tags: java, spring, spring-cache

I'm new to Spring Framework and trying to learn it. So I found some nice video tutorial explaining which I found to be good.

There's one part I couldn't understand though which I think is related with Spring EL he used together with the cache annotation in Spring.

This is the [video](https://youtu.be/g4h268Hx0AU?list=PLGDwUiT1wr6-Fn3N2oqJpTdhGjFHnIIKY&t=179) I watched.

And this is the part of code I'm wondering about.

```
    @Override
    @Transactional(
            propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED,
            readOnly = false)
    @CachePut(
            value = "greetings",
            key = "#result.id")
    public Greeting create(Greeting greeting) {
        logger.info("> create");

        if (greeting.getId() != null) {
            logger.error(
                    "Attempted to create a Greeting, but id attribute was not null.");
            throw new EntityExistsException(
                    "The id attribute must be null to persist a new entity.");
        }

        Greeting savedGreeting = greetingRepository.save(greeting);

        logger.info("< create");
        return savedGreeting;
    }
```

I'm wondering about the part where he used the annotation `@CachePut` and assigned the `key` parameter with `"#result.id"`. In the video he explained it is mapped with the ID of the response value. Which means the cache will save the ID of savedGreeting. Is that correct?

How does it work? I have looked in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) for Spring EL and could not find something about that there either. Anyone at Stackoverflow perhaps knows?

Comment: the ID is the `@Id` mapped in hibernate `Greeting.class`. The cache is stored in the browser so the next time you doing the HTTP request, it does not send a request to the DB, instead it gets it from the cache. `"greetings"` is the name of the cache manager you created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [Spring Cache documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cache-spel-context). That lists the keywords available when using the caching annotations. Basically: `#result` is the return value of the method and can be used in certain operations, like `@CachePut`.

Does that make sense?

Comment: oh, I didn't think about looking at the documentation for cache.

Comment: it does answer anyhow :)